# Certificate renewal fails with unauthorized/invalid response/404 .well-known/

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt, renewal

I understand this question is quite common and I have tried many attempts to fix this following many different variations on the theme. In the past I could not renew a let's encrypt cert at the 3 month expiry because of this error. I have since rebuilt the server and started again. This time however, I started with a staging certificate and it seems I am now stuck with that.

This is a rails server, running on ubuntu 20.04 with nginx, setup via Ansible per the book "Efficient Rails DevOps".

It cannot renew certificates as it complains the .well-known directory/page does not exist:

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for ------.com.au
Using default address 80 for authentication.
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain -----.com.au
http-01 challenge for -----.com.au
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: -----.com.au
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   https://-----.com.au/.well-known/acme-challenge/DQ2urLrKOSQmBhtlciFcbfMOcPIltmAAdI3vrijWrsM
   [103.208.218.34]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n  <title>The
   page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>\n  <meta
   name=\"viewport\" content"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I've taken out my attempts to resolve from the vhost conf file below, so it represents the original...

```
server {
  listen nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:80;
  listen nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:443 ssl;
  server_name www.dddd.com.au;
  return 301 https://dddd.com.au$request_uri;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dddd.com.au/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dddd.com.au/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dddd.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

}

server {
  listen nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:443 ssl;
  server_name dddd.com.au;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dddd.com.au/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dddd.com.au/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dddd.pem;
  root /var/www/dddd/application/public;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.dddd.com.au.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.dddd.com.au.log;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  ssl_session_tickets off;
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 5s;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
  add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    root /var/www/dddd/application/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header ETag "";
      break;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://dddd;
  }

  error_page 502 = @maintenance;

  location @maintenance {
    root /var/www/dddd/shared/maintenance;
    try_files $uri /index.html =502;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So...I've just had a development...I successfully deleted and re-issued the certificate as a full one.

I think I also found a location block for .well-known that works:

```

Answer (score 0):

So...I've just had a development...I successfully deleted and re-issued the certificate as a full one.

I think I also found a location block for .well-known that works:

```
location ~ ^/.well-known/ {
    allow all;
  }
```

...and inserted this into BOTH the server blocks (for port 80 and 443), as I performed a dry run renewal and no more errors...I got "Congratulations, all renewals succeeded..."

I'm happy to receive any corrections to this, as I'm still quite green with this stuff.

Thx.